# AIR : Which event is triggered when barcode reader scanning?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I have a USB barcode reader attached to my tablet ( running Android 2.2 ),
it seems to work, but :

- how to read the date from it ?, and
- which event is triggered when it is scanning ?

Comment: Does the barcode reader act as a keyboard input? i.e. if you open a search bar or any other place to type and scan a barcode do the contents of that barcode get pasted into your field? If so you should be able to treat it the same way as keyboard input inside your air application. So some sort of onKeyDown listener or something would work natively, Im not familiar with air, so I don't know how they expose that listener.

Comment: i tough it would act as a keyboard, and seems the android adding it as additional keyboard, anyway when i am scanning a barcode the result doesnt appear anywhere. I have tested with text fields, but without any positive result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would probably need some kind of Native Extension for that.

Comment: seems like there is no other choice, so i am going for it :)
Thank You.